# Reviving Elasticsearch 5.0.0

Tags: elasticsearch

My Elastic Stack is correctly up and running with Logstash , Kibana and Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch is running as a daemon (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start|stop etc...).

Sometimes due to low memory Elasticsearch fails and kibana status turns red. I obviously need to upgrade my memory and i did to 8 GB but still i want to be 100% sure that it will never crash/fail .

My question is how can i get Elasticsearch to run again as a daemon after it fails?

It fails rarely but it does.. so when it does i want it to run again.

My Elasticsearch version is 5.0.0 , im using ubuntu 16.04 and i followed these steps

https://github.com/DimitrisFilippou/Elastic-Stack-5.0

in addition , supervisor is not ideal for this issue because it can't handle daemons.

Comment: This might help understand your heap usage, maybe you can do something about it without increasing the memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741800/understanding-elasticsearch-jvm-heap-usage/35911980#35911980

Comment: @Val i will increase my memory anyway because i need logs from plenty of servers ... thanks for letting me know by the way i will take a look !